# Having problems in decoding from a JSON String in Firebase to a Map<String, Model> in Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart

I have this `UserData` model class that has a `Map<String, Model>`, in which `Model` is another model class.
When I do `jsonEncode` to Firebase's Firestore everything seems fine as it looks ok in the Firebase console, but when I try to `jsonDecode` back into the `UserData` model it's giving an error.
I have tried several ways to decode the map but it does not seem to want to work

```
//this is my UseData class


import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:sportmate/Models/user_sport_attributes.dart';

class UserData {
  final String name;
  final int age;
  final bool sex; //0 for male, 1 for female
  final GeoPoint location;
  final String bio;
  final Map<String, UserSportAttributes> sportsPlayed;
  final bool hasSetupAccount;

  UserData({
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
    required this.sex,
    required this.location,
    required this.bio,
    required this.sportsPlayed,
    required this.hasSetupAccount,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'Name': name,
        'Age': age,
        'Sex': sex,
        'Location': location,
        'Biography': bio,
        'SportsPlayed':
            jsonEncode(sportsPlayed), //chama o toJson automaticamente?
        'HasSetupAccount': hasSetupAccount,
      };

  static fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    Map<String, dynamic> sportsPlayedJson = jsonDecode(json['SportsPlayed']);
    return UserData(
        name: json['Name'],
        age: json['Age'],
        sex: json['Sex'],
        location: json['Location'],
        bio: json['Biography'],
        sportsPlayed: Map<String, UserSportAttributes>.from(
            sportsPlayedJson.map((key, value) =>
                MapEntry(key, UserSportAttributes.fromJson(value)))),
        hasSetupAccount: json["HasSetupAccount"]);
  }
}




//this is the other model class

class UserSportAttributes {
  final int level;
  final bool playedProfessional;
  final int yearsOfExperience;

  UserSportAttributes({
    required this.level,
    required this.playedProfessional,
    required this.yearsOfExperience,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'Level': level,
        'PlayedProfessional': playedProfessional,
        'YearsOfExperience': yearsOfExperience,
      };

  static fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserSportAttributes(
        level: json['Level'],
        playedProfessional: json['PlayedProfessional'],
        yearsOfExperience: json['YearsOfExperience']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're passing decoded json to your factory, no need to decode again here.

```
 Map<String, dynamic> sportsPlayedJson = jsonDecode(json['SportsPlayed']);
```

```
 factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
      name: json['name'] as String,
      age: json['age'] as int,
      sex: json['sex'] as bool,
      bio: json['bio'] as String,
      sportsPlayed: (json['sportsPlayed'] as Map<String, dynamic>).map(
        (k, e) =>
            MapEntry(k, UseRsPORTAttributes.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)),
      ),
      hasSetupAccount: json['hasSetupAccount'] as bool,
    );
```